# Cannot import 'commands' from Discord.ext

Tags: python, discord.py, pylance

My code:

```
import discord
from discord import commands
from discord import client

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong")


client.run("My_Token")
```

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Uers\ Username \Desktop\discordbot\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py)
```

And

[image]

**When I import discord: Discord is not accessed Playnce(greyed out)**

How I can fix this?

Comment: You’re not importing the commands extension from `discord.ext ` but from `discord `.

Answer (score 1):

The [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html?highlight=commands) extension is from `discord.ext`, not just `discord`:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong")

client.run("My_Token")
```

PS: Here, you don't need `client` and `discord` (that's why it was greyed out)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `discord.ext` to import the `commands` extension. And I believe you don’t need to import “Client” for this code

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=“!”)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(“Ready”)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
   await ctx.send(“Pong!”)

client.run(“My_Token”)
```